# Oracle and programming

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g, binary-data

I just wanted to know how I can store a picture in oracle data base ;

Comment: Your question is very broad in terms of the scope of ADO.NET. Is there a particular part of the problem you are struggling with or do you need to know everything from the point for creating the ORACLE database, connecting to the database using the oracle client and so on?

Comment: I think it's ok - it has the correct tags. Returned to 0.

Answer (score 1):

Well, as with anything in oracle, there are a handful of ways to store a photo. You can store it as a BLOB and should be pretty easy to implement loading photos into that type of field. A blob (in 10g) can store up to 8 terabytes in size.

You could also use the READ_IMAGE_FILE and WRITE_IMAGE_FILE functions built into oracle forms and use a RAW datatype as opposed to a BLOB datatype.

References:

[Asktom on READ_IMAGE_FILE and WRITE_IMAGE_FILE](http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0%3a%3a%3a%3aP11_QUESTION_ID:239814548726)

[Oracle 10g Native Datatypes - Overview of LOB Datatypes](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/datatype.htm#i3237)