# Programming and DataBase

Tags: c#, wpf, oracle

Hi
I have some questions:

1. can I make an animation using C# or I should just use WPF?  (I mean when I click on one button I want to see that button goes bigger and then smaller)
2. How can I insert a Film or a picture in my oracle database using sqlplus ?

Comment: @Aidin - Welcome to SO. You should ask this as 2 separate questions as they are totally unrelated.

Comment: @Aidin, you question(s) are very broad and you give very little details about what you try to do. You might read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints to improve your question asking skills.

Comment: @Admin , first question 1 , jquery is the best.

Comment: @gov How do you know that Aidin is using Web App? I think he is asking on Win App.

Comment: @Aidin - you asked a variant on the second question yesterday.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231894/oracle-and-programming One of the answers pointed to an OTN article which was a .Net solution.  You can also run that same anonymous PL/SQL in SQL*Plus.

Comment: Also, please don't post two unrelated questions in the same thread.  This is not how SO works.  Ask two separate questions.  There is no fee.

Comment: Question 2 has already been raised here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4231894/oracle-and-programming

Answer (score -3):

@Admin , first question 1 , jquery is the best

first question 2 , you should store the paths in the database but the real picture.should come..from  the image server, phyical paths.

Comment: If he's considering WPF, he's doing desktop development, not web development, so jQuery is hardly going to help him.

Comment: @Carson , May I know where did he say that he is going to use WPF , he is just looking for options.

Comment: @carson , his questions says " or I should just use WPF?"

Comment: for simple animations jquery is always better , WPF is almost advanced version of winforms , we really don't know what he is looking for , probably he should update his question whether he is doing webdevelopment or winforms development.

Comment: I agree, he should make it absolutely clear whether he's doing web or windows development. But if he's considering WPF, it's hard to imagine that he's doing web development.

Comment: @carson , where did he mention that he is going to use WPF or he is already in WPF development , he asked whether he can use WPF , we have to tell him various options and which one best suits for his requirements.

Comment: @serkan , you are right , but how can my answer is voted down, there is nothing wrong in my answer.

Comment: @gov In my opinion, your answer woted down (not me :) ) for giving wrong answer. Because as I understand too, Aidin going to make WinApp, not WebApp. So you cant suggest jQuery to him :)